# Group policy exclude security group

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have written a group policy and would like it to apply to the whole Active Directory except for one security group.

Unfortunately, the group policy is still applied to all users.

I have added the security group in "Advanced" in the delegation and ticked "Deny" in "Apply group policy". The "Read" option is also ticked.

Images:

- https://i.nlmyr.de/2fKR (GPO Delegation Configuration)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlUr9.png (GPO Delegation Full)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZcVy.png (Security Filter)

Comment: Without seeing the "full picture" (GPOs involved, settings in question, full permission patterns, GPO OU-linkage, processing sequence, user/computer part activation, RSOP from affected clients, ...) it is almost impossible to diagnose unexpected GPO behavior.
One possible reason which comes to my mind is "GPO loopback processing". If your GPO environment has enabled GPO loopback processing, the user GPOs will ignore permissions for users and apply also user-GPOs just based on permissions the system has on the GPOs.

Comment: @Halfix I edited it. Comment if you need more.

Comment: Even with the additional screenshots you provide just a pinhole view on the overall problem. No way to give any useful hints based on the provided information. If I were in your shoes I would start with investigation at an endpoint.
Have an affected user (where the settings don't arrive as expected; the account ideally should have local admin privileges and launch the cmd "as admin") execute this commandline:
gpresult /H c:\Temp\RSOP.htm
(if needed you can use any target folder or filename).
Within RSOP.htm search your GPO in question and the affected settings.

Comment: @Halfix hey thank you. Is there any way to get that report not for the user but for the PC? Because its a computer policy.

Comment: The report contains both, the computer settings and the user settings for the executing account.